# local printer in remote desktop

Tags: printing

I have connected my local computer in remote desktop connection utility. The client machine I am using is windows XP sp3 with .NET 3.5sp1 . I am connecting to windows 2003 server. However when I go to printer session in 2008 I could not see my local printer in server. I have checked local resources in client machine which establishing remote connection.

I have googled and found various fixes in GP, but could not get the result.

Is there something I am missing it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the drivers for that printer on the machine you are demoting into? If that machine doesnt have drivers it won't show up.

Comment: yes. I have installed the drivers in the remote machine. Still could not see my local printers in the remote session.

Comment: Finally I have fixed the problem.